# at a loss (meaning)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

I would like to know the meaning of "**at a loss**" in the following context.

I had a friend, a girl. One day I asked her to stop being friends. So she sent me a message saying:

> "Only God will know who is **at a loss** here... hmm is it you who loses
>   the potential of having a good friend or is it me ?"

What is "**at a loss**" expressing? I wonder if it is expressing something like "**in trouble**".

Comment: This sentence uses the idiom incorrectly. It may be that the person doesn't understand the idiom, or has heard it used incorrectly and is repeating the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be 'at a loss' means 'to not to know what to do or say', e.g. 'I'm at a loss to know how I can help you', 'it was unlike him to be at a loss for words'. It is followed by words specifying what the speaker cannot say or does not know, for example at a loss for words, at a loss to explain something, etc. It is unusual to just say 'at a loss' with nothing following. The expression 'who is at a loss here', in the context given, is not natural, and the following words make me think the speaker meant something like 'who is the loser here'.